# How to get react-table to be small, not in normal view

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I have used the react-table and generate the data with this table. The table looks great, but it is a bit too big for me. I wonder if there is a way to make the table to be a little bit smaller.

My actual result is the table being too big and horizontal/vertical scrolls are there. I am trying to expect the result that should show the table to be fit on the page without a scroll as possible.

I wonder if there is a table option to make it smaller instead of using CSS attributes. I am still learning how to be a better programmer. Anything will help a lot. Thank you!

Comment: According to the `react-table` documentations it doesn't provide any UI elements, your code does. If your UI elements are too big then *they* need to be trimmed down.

Comment: @DrewReese So, I guess CSS is the only way to trim down the table, right?

Comment: Well, a lot of libraries expose out the, or allow adding new, classnames to the compositional components used to build up the UI, but it appears `react-table` squarely places the UI responsibility on the consumer, i.e. us devs. On that note though, there are multiple options available for styling components in React, from the old CSS files and setting `className` or `id` on elements, using an in-line `style` prop, theming libraries like `styled-components`, to component libraries like Bootstrap/Material-UI/AntD. It, IMO, really just depends on what you're comfortable working with.